# convert date string to normal form?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a date in string form

```
[{"FromDate": "Wed Jan 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"}]
```

i want to print it in normal date form using date filter, but the problem is date is in string form. unless FromDate|date will work.
what to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter to convert string to timestamp and then format using angular date filter.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function ($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.date = [{"FromDate": "Wed Jan 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"}];

}])
.filter('parseDate', [function($filter) {
    return function(input){         
        return Date.parse(input);
    };
}])
```

Html

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
        {{date[0].FromDate | parseDate | date : 'fullDate'}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: let ihave several date object in one array. i need to print using ng-repeat in date form. 
whar i have to do?
simplest method?

Comment: You can create a custom filter to convert string to date object and format accordingly. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbajnw6v/)

Comment: can i covert it in the view side?

Comment: Yes you can, see the above fiddle